# In Python, can I define an instance method map() for the list class?

Tags: python

I was hoping to define an instance method `map()` or `join()` for the list class (for array).  For example, for `map()`:

```
class list:
    def map(self, fn):
        result = []
        for i in self:
            result.append(fn(i))
        return result

print [1, 3, 5].map(str)
```

Is it possible in Python to do that for the `list` class? (if not, can the last line `[1, 3, 5].map(str)` be made to work?)

Comment: I assume you're aware of the builtin `map(str, [1, 3, 5])`?

Comment: @Eric kind of want to write and use an instance method

Comment: Even so, you should probably implement your instance method as `def map(self, fn): return map(fn, self)`

Comment: @Eric I am just too imperative at the moment...

Comment: ['Map' may not be pythonesque](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) according to Guido.

Comment: @mistermarko does it mean `map()` the function or `map()` the method?  well, so if `map()` is not to be used, then say, how do you convert list of string to list of integer or vice versa?  By list comprehension?

Comment: @太極者無極而生: He obviously means the builtin function - Guido is unlikely to have commented on your method in this question. And yes, Guido would prefer `[str(x) for x in my_list]`

Comment: Of course, I meant to say 'pythonic'!

Answer (score 4):

Your code creates a new variable called `list`, which hides the original. You can do a little better by inheriting:

```
class mylist(list):
    def map(self, fn):
        result = []
        for i in self:
            result.append(fn(i))
        return result

mylist([1, 3, 5]).map(str)
```

Note that it is not possible to override `[]` to generate anything other than a `builtins.list`

---

So that leaves monkeypatching the builtin. [There's a module for that](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit), `forbiddenfruit`, which in its own words:

> may lead you to hell if used on production code.

If hell is where you're aiming for, then this is what you want:

```
from forbiddenfruit import curse
def list_map(self, fn):
    result = []
    for i in self:
        result.append(fn(i))
    return result
curse(list, "map", list_map)
```

```
print [1, 3, 5].map(str)
```

Comment: "Note that it is not possible to override [] to generate anything other than a builtins.list". Great that's it's not C++!

Comment: it is not possible to add an instance method for the built-in class `list`?

Comment: @太極者無極而生: Yes, but you probably shouldn't. See my update

Comment: "may lead you to hell if used on production code"... I thought our current world is the result of the "forbidden fruit" eaten by adam and eve